# How do popular iPhone RSS clients sync subscriptions with Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

Feedler and Mobile RSS have served me well in browsing my RSS subscription content that I added in Google Reader. What API are these apps using to get the list of subscriptions?

I want to create my own app that gets information from my Google Reader account (such as which items have been starred or tagged), but I don't see any reliable API that apps such as Feedler or Mobile RSS would be using. Do those apps pay a license fee to get access? Do they use some unreliable API?

Comment: Questions about APIs aren't a good fit here as they don't have a user interface. While Google Reader _is_ a web app, discussions of APIs are better at [so] or perhaps [programmers.se]. This _may_ be on-topic at [apple.se], but I doubt it. (Check the FAQ.) See also: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/740/are-api-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic

Comment: My apologies. If there's any way to move the topic, please do. Otherwise, is it okay to repost the question there or would that be spamming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Reader doesn't have an official API at present. Various [sources](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html) have suggested that one is/was intended, but seven years on there is still nothing.

Currently everyone is using the 'unofficial' API - a reverse engineering of the various AJAX calls the Google Reader web app makes. As with the recent [sudden disappearance](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/08/google-silently-kills-popular-api-breaks-weather-apps-everywhere/) of the unofficial Google weather API, this means using it runs the risk of unannounced changes or removal.

That said, there are [plenty](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=google%20reader%20API&oq=google%20reader%20API) of resources available to help with using it such as [this fairly comprehensive doco](http://undoc.in/googlereader.html). You should be able to find implementations in most languages as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That solves a lot of my doubts. I'll leave the question open a little longer before marking as correct, in case anyone has any more experience or insights they can share.

Comment: That undoc link is very useful. Does it mean if you know how to make REST service invocations you essentially have your desired API (with no guaranteed future support)?

Comment: That's right, the service itself is quite simple.